# Counting joins and limiting count

Tags: sql, count, hive

I am trying to return count of common movies that user a and b have in common. When I try to limit the results to `num >= 50`. I receive an error "Invalid table alias or column reference 'num'.

Do I need to use a correlated subquery?

If I do, can you please provide an example.

```
SELECT
a.user_id, b.user_id, count(*) AS num, collect_set(m.movie_title)
FROM
ratings a
JOIN
ratings b
ON
(a.movie_id = b.movie_id)
JOIN
movies m
ON
(a.movie_id = m.movie_id AND b.movie_id = m.movie_id)
WHERE
(a.user_id <> b.user_id AND num >= 50)
GROUP BY
a.user_id, b.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `HAVING count(*)>=50` after a `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thanks I thought someone had told me you can't use 'HAVING' in HIVE but it worked just fine.